# Minecraft Error Code

Tags: java, minecraft-forge

This is the end of the game output, can anyone tell me what to do? Thanks! I am using Minecraft 1.7.10 FML, Forge, IMSM, Treecapitator, Aether II, Backpacks, BiblioCraft, Brewcraft, Clienthax's Chococraft, Extra Doors, Fossil Archeology,FoxLib, Galacticraft Planets, Calacticraft Core, Gilded Games Utility, iChunUtil, Instant Blocks, Mantle, Minecraft Comes alive, More Enchantments, AencEx, More Furnaces, Mr. Crayfish's Furniture Mod, MusicCraft, RadixCore, Simple Flight, StairCraft, Tails, Twilight Forest, Xaero's Minimap, bspkrsCore, Red Gear Core, and the texture pack Love & Tolerance

Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: Exception java.lang.OutOfMemoryError occurred dispatching signal Unknown Signal to handler- the VM may need to be forcibly terminated

Comment: Looks like you ran out of memory.

Comment: How is this even programming related?

Answer (score 1):

You ran out of memory, you can increase it like so:
`java -XX:MaxPermSize=2048m`